# Drawing on picturebox vs directly on form

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am creating a lightweight GDI+ game engine in c#. I read some books that use a picturebox control as the graphics surface to draw on when creating a game engine. However after doing some research online it seems as if using a picturebox control is not what I should be doing. Is this true and if so why?

Comment: What has been your experience so far?  What have you tried and how has it failed?

Comment: It's fine, PictureBox does very little.  You get double-buffering for free so that's the typical reason you see this recommendation.

Comment: @HansPassant picturebox = double buffering; this is the type of key info I was looking for (wish i could mark it as the answer). Seeing as it's probably easy to implement my own double buffering solution I'll see how that goes, and if not I'll double back to using a picturebox.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any control, just draw directly on your form or a `Panel` with `DoubleBuffered` enabled. It's much better. You have to create your own objects so that we can calculate their `Region`, we'll use their `Region` to fill them on the form/panel. You have to handle the events `MouseMove`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` of your form/panel. Another problem is how to hittest your mouse with your `objects` so that we can control the objects according to the user behaviors. There is a useful method to do that called `IsVisible` of the `Region` object.

The reason we should not use any control for drawing here is we need some `Transparent` effect overlapped between objects, using `winforms` control can't help you achieve that easily if not wanting to say **impossible**, even you can achieve that, the effect is very poor. So just drawing everything on the same canvas. You should also try drawing on an `Image` instead, then draw that `Image` on your `form/panel` or implement your own `Double or triple buffered`. There are a lot to do but I hope you have some **important** notes with my answer and choose the right direction.